# How to continue when Python in Pycharm executes a command line process waiting on pause

Tags: python, cmd, process, pycharm, pause

I am using PyCharm to debug a piece of python code.  The python code executes a command line exe file which we wrote.  The exe program initially paused because it waits on a keypress, so we can attach the process for debug purpose.

When we run in cmd window, we can see the message and press any key to continue.  However, in PyCharm, I didn't see the message of waiting, and don't know how to let the process to continue.  Is there any where in PyCharm to interact with the CMD process started in python?